# Laravel subdomain routing is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, subdomain

I'm trying to have an admin subdomain ([like this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing))

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

but [admin.localhost](http://admin.localhost) acts just like [localhost](http://localhost).
How I'm supposed to do this correctly?

*I'm using Laravel 5.1 and MAMP on OSX*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Laravel processes routes on a first-come-first-serve basis and therefore you need to place your least specific routes last in the routes file. This means that you need to place your route group above any other routes that have the same path.

For example, this will work as expected:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "This will respond to requests for 'admin.localhost/'";
    });
});

Route::get('/', function () {
    return "This will respond to all other '/' requests.";
});
```

But this example will not:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "This will respond to all '/' requests before the route group gets processed.";
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "This will never be called";
    });
});
```

Comment: Better than i described!

Comment: This answer was a life saver!

Answer (score 3):

Laravel's example...

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.myapp.com'], function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Your code

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.localhost'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

If you look at the laravel example it gets the parameter `$account` in the route, this way we can route according to this variable. This can then be applied to the group or any route's in it..

That said, if it's not something driven by your database and you just want it with admin subdomain i would personally do this as a nginx config.

If you want to test nginx locally (easier) i personally recommended doing development with docker.

Hope this answers your question, if not let me know and ill try to answer for you.

Comment: Agree with you on this but the OP's question remains unanswered as to why its not working