# laravel subdomain error This page isn’t working

Tags: laravel

I making a route with a subdomain

```
Route::domain('qwe.asd.com')->group(function () {
Route::get('/mail',function(){
    echo "i am subdomain";
});
});
```

but its shows an error T"This page isn’t working".
my acchuel domain is asd.com

Comment: have you defined 'asd.com' in env ?

Comment: Aqid javed .my local host domain name is asd.com.and its work without subdomain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel subdomain routing is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703192/laravel-subdomain-routing-is-not-working)

Comment: why I define it in env

Comment: my url with subdomain is http://qwe.asd.com/mail  but it still not working.

Comment: but my problem is still not solved.